# Type Assertion in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have following code -

```
interface UserDTO {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const jsonData = {
    name: "John",
    age: 30,
    city: "New York", // Extra field not defined in UserDTO
};

const user: UserDTO = <UserDTO>jsonData;

console.log(user);
```

I am kind of perplexed how come the output is following -

```
{
  name: "John",
  age: 30,
  city: "New York"
}
```

Since interface object doesn't have this city field.

Actual Question - Let say I have a json which has multiple fields, and say i want to cast this json to a DTO which has although same structure but less fields. How can i do it? I don't want non relevant  fields in newly casted DTO. Thanks

Comment: Please see [`as` is not a cast](https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/as-is-not-a-cast.md)